# I am trying to make an missing number finder. Here is my code and the error I get

Tags: python, python-3.x

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHaoD.png)

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
  File "/home/QuartsPy/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 5, in main
    finished_data = sum(data)
  File "/home/QuartsPy/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
```

I keep getting this^^ error
I am trying to make a missing number finder. So I would enter in input 1,3,4 and it should send 2 in the console because that is the missing number.
This is my code:

```
def main():
    data = input()
    n = len(data)
    total = (n + 1)*(n + 2)/2
    finished_data = sum(data)
    print(total - finished_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting *as text* to the question.

Comment: That said, `data` is a `str` value. As an iterable, it's just a sequence of single-character strings; you need to convert *something* to, say, `int` values that can be added together.

Comment: `data` is just a string, you probably want to split it into individual numbers. Try `data = [int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Comment: I tried that but got this error: `Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,4'
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 2, in main
    data = int(input())
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()`

Comment: And this is why including all of the necessary information to reproduce your problem is needed. You'll want something like `data = [int(number) for number in input().split(',')]`

Comment: @tobias_k I tried that but got this answer: `Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,3,4'
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
    data = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 2, in main
    data = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()`

Comment: Ok thanks, @C.Nivs this worked!

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast every element of your input data as int

```
def main():
        data = input()
        n = len(data)
        total = (n + 1)*(n + 2)/2
        finished_data = sum(int(n) for n in data)
        print(int(total - finished_data))
```

Comment: With this, I get this error:
`Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    finished_data = sum(int(n) for n in data)
  File "/home/ilmart06/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 5, in main
    finished_data = sum(int(n) for n in data)
  File "/home/QuartzWarrior/Desktop/Python Random/Missing.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()`

Comment: You didn't mention you are using delimiter comma. anyways people have posted the updated answers

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the data type int to string.

```
def main():
data = input()
    n = len(data)
    # here you needs to convert datatype str to int
    total = int((n + 1)*(n + 2)/2)
    finished_data = sum(int(n) for n in data)
    print(total - finished_data)
```

Comment: With this, I get this error: https://pastebin.com/Rrf5Q4HD

Comment: @QuartsPy the error you got is indentation error. Try correcting the indentaion.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3, the result of `input()` is just a string, it is *not* evaluated as an integer, list or tuple.

Do do so, you have to `str.split` the list be the delimiter between the numbers, and then convert the parts to `int`, e.g. in a list comprehension. If the numbers are just separated by spaces, you can just use `input().split()`; it will split by all whitespaces by default.

In your case, judging by the error in your comments, they are separated by commas, so you have to explicitly provide the separator to `split`, i.e.:

```
data = [int(x) for x in input().split(',')]
```

You might also want to convert the result to `int` before printing, or use `//` instead of `/` so it does not become a `float`.